# Parse json from alfresco api

Tags: json, api, parsing, alfresco

a need parse son from alfresco API, but I have problem with two slashes in URL model address. How can I get value from "prejimka.stavHodnoceni"?  Can anyone help me ?

**My javascript:**

```js
var nazevSlozky = null;

var result = remote.call("/api/metadata?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/7d2eab73-9500-406a-bdb0-40209924b2d2");

var json = JSON.parse(result);

var nazevSlozky = json.properties.{http://ourFirm.cz/model/someFirm/3.0.}prejimka.stavHodnoceni;
```

**JSON:**
[My json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMzQj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try json.properties['sf:prejimka.stavHodnoceni'] where "sf" is the model abbreviation.

Also, I don't think you want to use punctuation in your property names. I'm not sure it is expressly forbidden but it seems like a bad idea.